# jQuery .append() string being garbled by IE7 html parser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

I finally have jQuery AJAX down pretty well and have my website all created, but now I've arrived at the dreaded IE bugfix stage.

I am trying to do something very basic: insert an extra css for IE7 users. I have this code:

```
if(navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 7.0") != -1)
    {
    var ieCSS = '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common-ie.css" />';
    $("head").append(ieCSS);
    }
```

The css is not applied to the page. However, I tested it with alert($("head").html()) and saw that for some reason most of the quotes and the / in my inserted html are being parsed out by the browser. This is what comes out:

```
'<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="common-ie.css">'
```

Why is this happening, and how can I get around it?

Comment: Hey, have you looked at conditional comments (http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)? They seem to be a better solution to your problem.

Comment: Iam3, I don't understand how that is at all different from what I have.

Comment: Shouldn't you have double quotes around `stylesheet` as well? Maybe IE arrives at this, then parses the rest of the `link` as HTML 4.0 or something.

Comment: The conditional comments allow you to include code (like link tags) that will only be rendered by certain versions of ie (IE less than 7, for example). They look like normal comments to other browsers and do not rely on JavaScript. They are both a clearer and more robust way to include IE-specific css than using jQuery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do the following instead of the javascript code your using. Insert this into the head tags like you would any of stylesheet.  This will only display for IE 7

```
<!--[if IE 7]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="common-ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and I will go with the conditional comments, but does anyone know why IE is botching my html string? It is just bothering me now.

Answer (score 0):

```
var ieCSS = "<link type='text/css' href='common-ie.css' />";
```

You have your quotes a bit off.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the quoting in the original question.

Comment: @Pointy There was actually, he fixed it. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is not related with IE 7. its merely a quotation error. Here is the fixed version:

```
var ieCSS = "<link type=\"text/css\" href=\"common-ie.css\" />";
```

Comment: So the quotation was ok, then don't bother with this answer.

Comment: Yeah, I mixed up pasting the garbled IE output with the version I inputted.

Answer (score 0):

You could do, havent tested it.

```
var ua = $.browser;
    if ( ua.msie && ua.version.slice(0,3) === "7.0" ) {
          var ieCSS = "<link type=\"text/css\" href=\"common-ie.css\" />";
        $("head").append(ieCSS);    
          }
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the quoting in the original question.